# syntax for reusable function types in function declarations

Tags: flowtype

This is how you annotate a variable / constant as holding a function of a particular type:

```
declare type TFunction = () => any;
const foo: TFunction = function foo() {};
```

What is the syntax when one *declares* a function:

```
function boo() {}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to put`: TFunction` on your `function boo()` declaration.  However, you can flow check it by writing the no-op statement `(boo: TFunction);` afterward.  The only drawback is this evaluates `boo` at runtime.

Probably the best way to do it though is to not worry about explicitly declaring that `boo` is a `TFunction`, and instead just rely on Flow to check it any time you use `boo` where a `TFunction` is expected.

Here's a more concrete example of what I mean: ([Try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCATgJYYAWAtnhqQMYDy+xAhnXAHZgC8YAFKwBcYTgFcqAIzzEANGEkjxUmQEpeAPlETpxANzooYzvQ7dWAEwuClOmfMXaVxVbedgA3qjBhitMcTmYADUCgYAvobGpqRcYPRc9Ow2YADOGGScAOYOIumZWa5pGaTZnt6+-oFgrCFhqJGoRiZmYFBwMNasxGxYIiS9ADzKuhrycCzssZz9ZJQ0dEyTZkUjMuU+fhgB5j2sWAB0fhZi9Hj8EzJTXKoRhh3WANoAjPIATPIAzAC68pYWtzAwGAYDgAGsFHgkmJUgR-mAqOx6BQ8KkiHNqLQGMwrmYmg9+C93l9fvFEuxAcC2vAkDJiHBiJDobCySZ2GALHBUZwAOQYBFIiioIA))

```
/* @flow */

type ArithmeticOperation = (a: number, b: number) => number;

function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}

function concat(a: string, b: string): string {
  return a + b;
}

function fold(array: Array<number>, operation: ArithmeticOperation): number {
  return array.reduce(operation);
}

fold([1, 2, 3], add); // ok because add matches ArithmeticOperation
fold([1, 2, 3], concat); // flow error because concat doesn't match
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to this question, but if you are talking about declarations in the sense of "compile-time declarations, separate from code, that use the `declare` keyword", then per the [Flow declarations docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html), you should be able to declare globals like this:

```
declare var boo: TFunction;
```

or scoped items as members of their containing module or type:

```
declare class FunctionHolder {
  boo: TFunction;
}
```